# How can I evaluate $ \frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x} dy \; f(y) \int_{0}^{y} dz \; f(z) $ correctly?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Naively I thought that since the second factor does not depend on $x$, I can use 
$$\frac{d}{dx}  \int_0^x f(y) dy = f(x)$$
to find
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x} dy \; f(y) \int_{0}^{y} dz \; f(z) = f(x)  \int_{0}^{y} dz \; f(z) \, . $$
But this obviously can't be correct because the second integral still depends on the integration variable of the first integral, which is no longer present in the formula.

How can I evaluate $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x} dy \; f(y) \int_{0}^{y} dz \; f(z)$ correctly?

(I suspect that the correct answer is $f(x)  \int_{0}^{x} dz \; f(z) $ but I'm not sure how to show it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *almost* replaced all the $y$s with $x$s.  Why did you stop?

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} &\int_0^x \mathrm{d}y \, f(y) \int_0^y \mathrm{d}z \, f(z)    \\
&=
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_0^x \left( f(y) \int_0^y f(z) \,\mathrm{d}z \right) \,\mathrm{d}y  \\
&= f(x) \int_0^x f(z) \,\mathrm{d}z  \\
&= f(x) \int_0^x \mathrm{d}z \, f(z)  \text{.}  
\end{align*}